# Best way to visualize CFG of a broken LLVM function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, control-flow-graph

I need to visualize the CFG of an LLVM Function, which I have in a `.ll` file. There is the `opt` tool, which has the `--view-cfg` option. However, the problem is that the function is broken, the definition of a register does not dominate all its uses. I need to view the CFG to investigate why this is the case. Problem: `opt` does not take wrong LLVM functions, so I cannot view the CFG with it.

So, what is the best way to visualize the CFG of a broken LLVM function?

Answer (score 3):

> Problem: `opt` does not take wrong LLVM functions, so I cannot view the CFG with it.

That's not actually the case. The verifier is turned on by default, yes, but if the function in question is *syntactically* correct, then you can just turn it off:

```
$ opt -disable-verify -view-cfg foo.ll
```

[image: Result of <code>opt -disable-verify -view-cfg</code>]

You can even try to compile it with `llc`, run with `lli`, etc this way.